# Pushing a flatlist item up or down

Tags: react-native

I have a flatlist. The flatlist contains todos that I can add, edit and delete.
I have two buttons on each todo-item, one for up and one for down.

If I want to push them up 1 step (until it reaches 0) or down (until it reaches the last item) how would I do this? Help is much appreciated, this feels basic but I can't seem to find an answer that works.
Here is my code:

```
<FlatList
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
            data = {todos.sort(function(a,b){return b.date - a.date})}
            keyExtractor={(item)=>item.key}
            renderItem={({item})=>{
            return(
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <View>
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.toDoItem} 
                            value={item.title}
                            onChangeText={(text)=>handleUpdateText(text, item)}
                            multiline={true}
                            maxLength={55}    
                            blurOnSubmit={true}   
                            />      

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handleMoveUp(item.key, item)}>
                                <FontAwesome name="plus-circle" size={30} color={black}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handleMoveDown(item.key, item)}>
                                <FontAwesome name="minus-circle" size={50} color={black}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FlatList's data must first be stored into a state.

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
```

Since you are sorting the initial states in your `FlatList` according to their dates, it might be useful to do this exactly once in the following `useEffect`.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
   let temp = [...todos]
   temp.sort(function(a,b){return b.date - a.date})
   setTodos(temp)
}, [setTodos])
```

We could also do this directly in the initial state.

Use `todos` of your state in your `FlatList`.

```js
<FlatList
   data = {todos}
...

</FlatList

...
```

Then, implement a function that alters the state of your items as follows.

```js
 const handleMoveUp = React.useCallback(
    (index) => {
      if (index !== 0) {
        let prevState = [...todos]
        let temp = prevState[index - 1]
        prevState[index - 1] = prevState[index]
        prevState[index] = temp
        setItems(prevState)
      }
    },
    [setTodos, todos]
  )
```

add this function as the `onPress` function of your `TouchableOpacity` that moves items up, that is

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handleMoveUp(item.key)}>
    <FontAwesome name="plus-circle" size={30} color={black}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The process for `moving down` is implemented in a very similar fashion. Just use the same code as in `handleMoveUp` but increase the index instead of decreasing it.

Comment: Thank you man. I will try this first thing tomorrow, do you mind explaining why you're using useCallback? I don't quite understand what it specifically does.

Comment: You are welcome!. `useCallback` makes a function stable. It will only change if its dependencies changes, which we provide using a dependency array. Take a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll get back to you tomorrow!

Comment: This was great, thanks. However I seem to have a problem with my sort function. Maybe it has to do with other functions in my code. How would I write the sort directly in the initial state?

Comment: You are welcome. Have you added the above `useEffect`? This should do the sorting excactly once after the component is mounted. You can also do this directly in the initial state by using `const [todos, setTodos] = useState(data.sort(function(a,b){return b.date - a.date}))`. I hope this works.

Comment: Where `data` are your todos. I can't see from your post where this is comming from.

Comment: I had made an error related to a different function, so your solution worked perfectly. Thank you again